# iOS: How to drag a view along with finger till a particular y offset?

Tags: objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer, smooth-scrolling

I am dragging a view from bottom to top with pre-defined offset positions using pan gesture.

My current implementation is such that the view updates after the gesture has ended. However, I want the view to update along with the finger (gesture is ongoing) and stop at the predefined (next) position when the gesture has ended.

Would appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction. Thank you.

m_openPercentage = @"30,60";

```
- (void)onContentViewPanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint velocity = [gesture velocityInView:self.view];
    NSArray *m_Openpercentage = [m_OpenPercentage componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSMutableArray *fullpercentage = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:m_Openpercentage];
    float diffy = 0.0;
    if(([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded))
        {
            if(velocity.y < 0)
            {
                if(m_isfullscreen && ![fullpercentage containsObject:@"100"])
                {
                    [fullpercentage addObject:@"100"];
                }
                diffy = 1-([[fullpercentage objectAtIndex:counter] floatValue]/100);
                CGFloat ypos = self.view.frame.size.height * diffy;
                [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:0.5 options:0 animations:^{
                    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
                    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,ypos,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
                    if(self.view.frame.origin.y==0)
                        [self showNavigationbar:1];
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                }];

                if(counter<[fullpercentage count]-1)
                    counter++;


            }
            else
            {
                    if(counter>0)
                {
                    float diffy = 1-([[fullpercentage objectAtIndex:counter-1] floatValue]/100);
                    CGFloat ypos = self.view.frame.size.height * diffy;

                    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:0.5 options:0 animations:^{
                        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,ypos,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


                    }];
                }
                else
                {
                    diffy = 1-(m_initialPercentage/100);
                    CGFloat ypos = self.view.frame.size.height * diffy;

                    if(self.view.frame.origin.y < ypos)
                    {

                    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:0.5 options:0 animations:^{
                        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,ypos,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    }];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [self removeoverlayview];
                        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                        id tmpControllerObj = [parentController getParentController];
                        [tmpControllerObj view].userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                    }
                }

                if((counter-1)>=0)
                    counter--;
                [self showNavigationbar:0];
            }
            if(![m_Openpercentage containsObject:@"100"] && m_isfullscreen)
                [self updatefullview];
        }

}
```

Comment: You should use `UIGestureStateChanged` state of pan gesture and update your view relatively with every location change. For relative calculation you can use a static variable or a class variable which will store the last updated location in the process. It should be pretty simple and straight forward.

Comment: I have tired with UIGestureStateChanged but i am facing some problem.When i move the view up it is going fully and then comes down.Dont know where i am going wrong.